# Problem using Slidable with onPressed. (flutter_slidable: ^1.2.0)

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble with `flutter_slidable: ^1.2.0`.
Looking at the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

class SlidableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final void Function(BuildContext context) onDismissed;

  const SlidableWidget({required this.child, required this.onDismissed, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Slidable(
        child: child,
        endActionPane: const ActionPane(motion: ScrollMotion(), children: [
          SlidableAction(
            flex: 1,
            onPressed: this.onDismissed(context),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            icon: Icons.delete,
            label: 'Delete',
          ),
        ],
        extentRatio: 0.2,),
      );
}
```

I want `onDismissed` function to be passed as a parameter but on the line `onPressed: this.onDismissed(context)`, it isn't right. It says `Invalid const value`. But I don't know what is wrong and how to solve it.  Can anyone explain me?


Thank you so much.

Sura

Comment: remove `const` keyword in this line `endActionPane: const ActionPane(motion: ScrollMotion(), children: [` maybe it's work.

Comment: Yes, it worked.  Thank you so much Mr. Bagjani.

Answer (score 5):

Remove "const" before ActionPane

then you can use this:

onPressed:(BuildContext context){

},